# "Cannot find name 'div'.ts(2304)" when creating a new React application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have created a new React application with the command: "npx create-react-app poi-search --template typescript".
When opening the files, ESLint asked me for permission. After that there were only errors. Picture here: [image]

I have the latest version of VSCode.

Here my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
```

}

This is the automatically generated configuration.

Comment: what's your npm version ?? via this command: npm -v

Comment: 6.9.0 is my npm version

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a VSCode's bug. Here is a few ways you could use to fix it.

1. Just restart VSCode.
2. If you don't want to close VSCode. You could press **⇧⌘P** / **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type `reload`. Then select `Developer: Reload Window` to reload VSCode.

All worked for me.